# How to use CreateProcessAsUser with argument is japanese?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-services

I write windows service to start an application with specified path and send a file name as its argument. => I use `CreateProcessAsUser` on `C#` code:

1. If file name is from a,b,c...z character => success
2. If file name is Japanese => The file name is got at application to be not correct

*P/S: I debugged windows service: file name passed to `CreateProcessAsUser` is correct, But at application is not.*

**Question: How Can I get file name correctly when It is Japanese?**

**UPDATE: Using `CreateProcessAsUserW()`**

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateProcessAsUserW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public extern static bool CreateProcessAsUserW(IntPtr hToken, String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandle, int dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            String lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);
```

Comment: Use the Unicode version, CreateProcessAsUserW

Comment: CreateProcessAsUserW will only work if the application in question supports Unicode file names.  If not, you might have to change the code page, which I think you do using SetLocaleInfo().  I'm not sure what the side-effects might be from changing the code page for the system account, or if that is even possible.

Comment: @CoreTech I cannot find the dll of `CreateProcessAsUserW`, so I change `CreateProcessAsUser` by adding `W` to it. **Is it right?**

Comment: No, CharSet should be Unicode, not Ansi, when calling the W version.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Now I resolved this issue. I use `CreateProcessAsUser` and all structures with `Charset = CharSet.Unicode`. Add `dwCreationFlags` with `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` in all of structures and `CreateProcessAsUser` routine